# Rest API - /interaction/v1/interactions/{id}

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, python

In the definition of the Rest API call for interactions it calls for and ID.  What is this ID, and can you get a list of them from other API calls, if so which API call?

[API-GetInteractionByID](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/getInteractionById.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID requested in this call is the External Key defined in the interaction you created. See below for sample image:

[image]

From a REST call, I am not sure if there is a way to gather all the IDs, but I believe using a retrieve request from SOAP should be able to do it (http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/retrieverequest/)